# Get all searched strings only

Tags: notepad++

I have a big file with long lines.
I want to get the values matching my regex only.

My line:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX;XXXXXXXXXXXX;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;666=0;XXXXXXXXXXXXXX;XXXXXXXXXX;XXX
```

I need to get only the value right after 665 in all lines. example:  ;665=.;

so results should look like:

```
;665=1;
;665=5;
;665=B;
;665=AB;
```

And not the whole lines.
The reason is that the result is always truncated in the search window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+(;666=[^;\r\n]+;).+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    (           # group 1
        ;666=       # literally
        [^;\r\n]+   # 1 or more non semicolon and non linebreak
        ;           # a semicolon
    )           # end group
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]